# Uninstall memcached and/or (force) install with Homebrew - Mac OS X

Tags: memcached, homebrew

I need a memcached on my Mac (os X 10.8), and I began by installing memcached and libevent 'manually' (1). 
Well, maybe I did this a bit too quickly, and now I'm figuring out that it would be better to install it 'cleanly' with Homebrew.

I think I should first uninstall 'cleanly' libevent and memcached. Should I ? 
Or should I simply run `brew install memcached` , and use the function to delete the files Homebrew thinks are to be deleted ? (I mean `brew link -f memcached` after `brew install memcached` ; I'm wondering how 'clean' it will be , and if I won't encounter problems hard to solve later on ...)

Thanks for your help !

---

(1) how I installed libevent:

```
cd /tmp
wget http://www.monkey.org/~provos/libevent-1.4.13-stable.tar.gz
tar zxvf libevent-1.4.13-stable.tar.gz
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

and memcached :

```
wget http://memcached.googlecode.com/files/memcached-1.4.1.tar.gz
tar xzvf memcached-1.4.1.tar.gz
cd memcached-1.4.1
./configure
make
make test
sudo make install
memcached -d -P pidfile -l 127.0.0.1
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both Memcached & libevent ship with a Makefile `uninstall` target-command. Assuming you still have your previously configured source files; else, you need to run `./configure` before running any make commands.

```
cd memcached-1.4.1
sudo make uninstall
cd ../libevent-1.4.1-stable
sudo make uninstall
```

Afterward, you should be able to install everything cleanly with Homebrew.

Comment: Thks! For the record, I had to download again the sources, because the `make install` deleted those, and as you indicated, re-run `./configure`.